# find the hermitian operator of an operator which attaches a matrix and its iverted

Tags: abstract-algebra, linear-transformations, inner-products, adjoint-operators, hermitian-matrices

$V=M_n\left(\mathbb{C}\right)$ with the standard inner product $<A,B>=tr\left(B^{*}A\right)$ and let $P\in V$ be an invertible matrix. We define an operator $T_p:V->V$ such that $$T_p\left(A\right)=P^{-1}AP$$

I need to find $adj(T_p)$

I tried by definition and it didn't workout too much for me, and also if I could express $T_p$ in the standard base, and then use $\left[T^{*}\right]_B=\left[T_B\right]^{*}$, but I don't see how to express $T_p$ in such way, so I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: if $A, B\in V$, then $tr(A B) = tr(B A)$

Using this rule, try to find a matrix $C$ depending on $B$ such that
\begin{equation}
\langle T_p(A), B\rangle = \langle A, C\rangle
\end{equation}

Comment: ok, so by definition of the inner product, I get trace(P^(-1)APB*)=trace(AC*), what can I conclude from here ?
if C=T*(B). It means that T* = adjoint and transpose, Tp*(B)=B*?

Comment: How do you get trace(P^(-1)APB*)=trace(AC*) ?

Comment: using the adjoint operator definition. <Tp(A), B>=<A,Tp*(B)> and using Tp(A) = P^(-1)AP, and then the inner product definition.

Comment: You are mixing up two notations, the star in $C^*$ where $C$ is a matrix, which means the conjugate of the transposed matrix and the star in $T_p^*$ which means the adjoint operator. These are not the same operations. Use $Adj(T_p)$ for example to avoid confusion.

Comment: ok, fixed it in the question.